# TFS 2010 Promotional Models

Tags: tfs

What are some of the models/methods (best practices) to promote code between environments?  What kind of models do you use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*What are some of the models/methods (best practices) to promote code between environments?*

A good place to start looking is looking at the [Microsoft Team Foundation Server Branching Guidance: Code Promotion Best Practices](http://branchingguidance.codeplex.com/).  This version is for 2008 but will get you started in understanding approaches.

From there, take a look at the [Visual Studio TFS Branching Guide 2010](http://Visual%20Studio%20TFS%20Branching%20Guide%202010).  Download the [TFS_Branching_Guide_2010_Complete_Package](http://tfsbranchingguideiii.codeplex.com/releases/38849/download/101774).  Inside you will find a variety of diagrams/documents that will assist you in deciding how to best approach code promotion.

*What kind of models do you use?*

Our company model varies from project to project due to the complexity and release model.  In all cases though we have separate branches for each release/hotfix and a main branch which acts as the pulse of our application "A build that should never fail."  From there though we use a variety of approaches- some using a Review WI before promotion, others a bit more free in the promotion process.  All that to say, based on your scenario and goals you will find your approach adjusting to fit those needs.

Comment: +1 for refering the Rangers' work on branching. I consider it the bible of centralized VCS systems.